# Uncaught ReferenceError timeout is not defined but it actually works

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(".title").click(function () {
  if ($(this).parent().hasClass("is-closed")) {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("is-closed");
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .css("max-height", parseInt($(this).next().height()) + parseInt(80));
    timer = window.setTimeout(() => {
      $(this).parent().css("max-height", "inherit");
    }, 500);
  } else {
    $(this).parent().addClass("is-closed");
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .css("max-height", parseInt($(this).next().height()) + parseInt(80));
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      $(this).parent().css("max-height", "50px");
    }, 2);
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
  }
});
```

I have an accordion menu and basically, I set max-height inherit after some time when it opened. (I do this because when resizing the browser not all content is visible. Because when minimizing the browser content has more height.)

Anyway, the code works fine. It does what I want. But in Chrome Console, I see this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: timer is not defined

`window.clearTimeout(timer);` throws the error.

Is it something I should be concerned about?

Comment: which line of your code throws that error

Comment: window.clearTimeout(timer); throws the error.

Comment: Use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) and don't use implicit global variables. You'll write better code as a consequence. TL;DR put `let timer;` above this code

Comment: @Phil Thank you. I added let timer; and no more errors.